# Filtering Wikidata Search

Tags: wikidata, search-engine

Wikidata today is not only an ontology but also a catalog of publications: scientific articles, formal documents (law), etc. are registered, millions of Wikidata-items.  So, when using [Wikidata's  search engine](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?sort=relevance&search=test&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&advancedSearch-current=%7B%7D&ns0=1&ns120=1) it is looking for  millions  of **things that I not need**.

How to say to Wikidata-search that I not need that?

---

Can I use the [SparQL engine](https://query.wikidata.org/) as search engine?

Articles are subclass of [*work*](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q386724) (`Q386724`), so can I exclude that items and do a ordinary search for others?

Comment: https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:WikibaseCirrusSearch

Comment: @StanislavKralin This is the answer!  It is working on Wikidata, for example *"haswbstatement:P31=Q5  Mary"*.

Comment: Then write the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As @StanislavKralin suggested, read [the guide](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:WikibaseCirrusSearch) (!). Some examples in the context of the question.

---

Supposing that I am looking for itens about *"personal data"* on Wikidata search box.

- Try `personal data`... 
  Results in a lot of strange items (example [Q3328..](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q33280464)), that, when click we can see that are journal article (Q13442814) instances.
- add the `haswbstatement:` tag with the entity tag. For example `personal haswbstatement:P31=Q151885` retrieves all instances of Q151885 that have key-word "personal".
- To search for items that do not have a certain statement, add an “exclude” modifier.
  `personal data -haswbstatement:P31=Q13442814` finds all "personal data" excluding journal articles.
- `personal data -haswbstatement:P279=*` retrieves all ontological itens that are a kind of subclass (so not is a kind of article, document or any other non-ontological item).